# setMaxResults with huge tables uses too much memory

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, hql

I am using *Hibernate* and I would like to execute this query :

```
SELECT s.executionTime, g.date, s.name
FROM SimulationStatsGroup g
LEFT JOIN SimulationStats s ON s.group_id = g.id
WHERE g.name = 'general'
ORDER BY g.date DESC
LIMIT 30
```

In this query I have to tables and 1 `SimulationStatsGroup` contains several `SimulationStats`.

However, with *HQL*, `LIMIT` generates an error because *hibernate* does not support it.
So I used `setMaxResults(int)` instead but when I look for the query in the logs I can see there is no `LIMIT` at all.

This is probably because *Hibernate* knows that a `SimulationStatsGroup` can contain several `SimulationStats`, thus it knows that limiting to 30 results won't return 30 `SimulationStatsGroup` as wanted but 30 rows, which will give me 3 `SimulationStatsGroup` if we assume there are 10 `SimulationStats` in 1 `SimulationStatsGroup`.

So, I can understand why it's working this way and not how I would like. But, this way of executing the query makes my application crashing because it uses too much memory because I have more than 1 million rows in my tables, and it seems that *Hibernate* is trying to put all rows in a list.

My question is : is there a way to limit to the use of the memory to keep my application alive and only keeping my 30 objects ?

Comment: Please include your actual code.

Comment: I guess hibernate may let you load SimulationStats lazily. Please also include how you're mapping your entities to tables. I mean, I think hibernate will first execute the query and only after that it will create objects and fill them with values (not sure, but it makes sense for me), so you may have to tell hibernate not to load your stats by default.

Comment: The Postgres driver by default, buffers the complete result in memory. You can change that through the JDBC API, but I don't know if you can do that through Hibernate: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/query.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For very large table I suggest you use [the seek method](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) but it requires running native queries and each database has it's own way of restricting rows number.

In your case you could simply run two queries instead of one:

- the first query simply return the parent ids:

  ```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Query query = session.createQuery("select ssg.id from SimulationStatsGroup ssg");
  query.setFirstResult(0);
  query.setMaxResults(10);
  List<Long> ids = query.list();
  ```
- then you can use a second query to fetch the parent with children:

  ```
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  Query query = session.createQuery("select ssg from SimulationStatsGroup ssg left join fetch ssg.simulationStats where ssg.id in (:ids) ");
  query.setParameterList("ids", ids);
  List<SimulationStatsGroup> simulationStatsGroups = query.list();
  ```

This way you can bypass Hibernate in-memory Parent-Child grouping limitation.

Comment: I never thought about using 2 queries like this. This is working fine, thank you!